# Installing Ubuntu Server on AMD chipset RAID array

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a TRX40-based baremetal machine. In order to ensure the availability of this machine, I want to boot the OS from a RAID1 array. This has proved harder than expected.

In the BIOS I have used RaidXpert2 to create the array. But in the Ubuntu Server installer, it shows the underlying drives instead of the array. I did some Googling and found that I apparently need drivers for AMD RAID to work. This was surprising to me, as my past experience with RAID has been using the RAID Controllers on HP ProLiant servers, and in those RAID seems to be transparent, the OS sees the array just like it would a hard drive. The drivers were only required in order to check the health of the underlying drives and to manage the array within the OS. HP RAID controllers also hide drives that are in an array from the OS. Because of these differences, I don't really have a mental model of how AMD RAID is supposed to work.

I've read that the easiest way to get AMD RAID working on Ubuntu is with the [rcraid-dkms](https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms) package. Unfortunately I am having issues with this. Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried following [these instructions](https://thopiekar.eu/other/amd-raidxpress/) but was unable to as the Ubuntu Server install USB does not have a try without installing/live environment option.
2. I tried following the Ubuntu Server install procedure, then when I got to the storage configuration part of the install wizard choosing Help > Enter Shell and following [these instructions](https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms#debianubuntu). `sudo apt-get install rcraid-dkms` fails with an error about a read-only filesystem.
3. I tried installing Ubuntu Server on one of the hard drives in the array while in AHCI mode, then using the instructions on the repo to switch from AHCI mode to RAID mode. Unfortunately the system continues booting from just a single drive. (Also even after installing rcraid-dkms and enabling it via `modprobe`, `lsblk` does not show the array. `dmesg` does not mention the array either.)
4. I tried removing the array, installing Ubuntu Server on a single drive, then creating an array. It seems creating an array destroys the filesystem though, as Ubuntu Server is not bootable afterwards.

I'm kind of surprised by how difficult this is. How can I install Ubuntu Server on an AMD RAID array?

Comment: Sounds like FakeRAID. I had no idea AMD had invented their own FakeRAID but sure enough it looks like they did. I'd ignore it and go pick up a cheap (real) RAID HBA.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the PCIe slots to spare for a RAID controller. Also, I was under the impression that booting from FakeRAID was impossible (because the drivers would be stored on the array, so to access them you would need the drivers), but AMD have instructions for booting Windows from their RAID, and rcraid-dkms has instructions for Ubuntu (non-server).